# How add new field on tree view (inherit on inherited)

Tags: xpath, replace, field, odoo, addition

I'm trying to replace a field in a tree view. Help me please.

This is script on base odoo enteprice

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_task_form2_inherited">
        <field name="name">project.task.form.inherited</field>
        <field name="model">project.task</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="project_id" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="on_change">onchange_project(project_id)</attribute>
            </field>
            <field name="tag_ids" position="after">
                <field name="analytic_account_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="progress" widget="progressbar"
                            groups="project.group_time_work_estimation_tasks"/>
            </field>
            <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='description_page']" position="after">
                <page string="Timesheets" groups="project.group_tasks_work_on_tasks,project.group_time_work_estimation_tasks">
                <field name="timesheet_ids" groups="project.group_tasks_work_on_tasks" context="{'default_account_id' : analytic_account_id, 'default_is_timesheet' : 1}">
                    <tree editable="top" string="Timesheet Activities">
                        <field name="date"/>
                        <field name="user_id" required="1"/>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="account_id"/>
                        <field name="unit_amount" string="Duration" sum="Total time" widget="float_time"/>
                        <field name="is_timesheet" invisible="1"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
                <group>
                 <group class="oe_subtotal_footer oe_right" name="project_hours" groups="project.group_time_work_estimation_tasks">
                    <field name="effective_hours" widget="float_time" groups="project.group_time_work_estimation_tasks"/>
                    <field name="remaining_hours" widget="float_time" class="oe_subtotal_footer_separator" groups="project.group_time_work_estimation_tasks"/>
                 </group>
                </group>
            </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

This is my custom script on _view.xml:

```
    <record id="project_task_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">project.task.view.form</field>
        <field name="model">project.task</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">              
            <xpath expr="/notebook/page[@name='description_page']" position="replace">
                <page string="Timesheets" groups="project.group_tasks_work_on_tasks,project.group_time_work_estimation_tasks">
                <field name="timesheet_ids" groups="project.group_tasks_work_on_tasks" context="{'default_account_id' : analytic_account_id, 'default_is_timesheet' : 1}">
                    <tree editable="top" string="Timesheet Activities">
                        <field name="date"/>
                        <field name="user_id" required="1"/>
                        <field name="name"/>                                                        
                        <field name="unit_amount" string="Duration" sum="Total time" widget="float_time"/>
                        <field name="is_timesheet" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="invoiceable_analytic_line"/>                            
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I want add new field `"invoiceable_analytic_line"` inside `"timesheet_ids"`, but it doesn't work.

anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: invoiceable_analytic_line is one2many fields ??

Comment: You should inherit from module_of_view.view_task_form2_inherited instead of project.view_task_form2 (change module of view for the name of the module that adds that view).

plus i recommend you to do this insead of all that expression:

<field name="is_timesheet" position="after">
    <field name="invoiceable_analytic_line"/>                            
</field>

This should be enough in your view for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**View**
The procedure is correct but just that there is an error with the  **expr** attribute inside **xpath**.
Instead:
`<xpath expr="/notebook/page[@name='description_page']" position="replace">`,
you have to write:
`<xpath expr="//sheet/notebook/page[1]" position="replace">` 
when on **odoo 10**
`<xpath expr="/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Description']" position="replace">`
Because **description_page doesn't exist**
So copy whole `<page string="Description">..</page>` tag from **/project/project_view.xml** and paste it inside your **xpath tag** by modify the string. After that insert your field where you want

**Model**

```
class Add_in_timesheet(models.Model)
    _inherit = 'project.task
    invoiceable_analytic_line = fields.Char(string=u"Invoiceable")
```

[image: picture from odoo8/addons/project/project_view.xml]